# R function get wrong

Tags: r, function

I edited my code below, but get another error message

```
#get the path name
dir <- 'W:/project/_help/temp/'
#get file name only under the path
files <- list.files(dir,pattern = '*.txt')
#get file name with full path information, may content subfolder
filepath <- list.files(dir,pattern = '*.txt', full.names = TRUE)

#the library for get var bb in function
library(tidyr)

#----------------------------------------------built function below:
r_overall <- function(xx){
  aa <- readLines(filepath)
  bb <- subset(aa, grepl(xx, aa)==TRUE )
  cc <- readr::parse_number(bb)
  return(cc)
}
r_overall <- lapply(xx, "The probability of being a carrier is")
```

after run this, I got an error message: "Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :
object 'The probability of being a carrier is' of mode 'function' was not found", how can I fix it? and if the value is NA in the string, how can I handle it as missing value? Thank you. TGG

Comment: You're trying to assign values to `r_overall` twice. Do you mean to use `r_overall` as the function applied by `lapply`? It's unclear why you're setting up the syntax this way—you haven't given `lapply` a function

Comment: You can [edit] the post to include additional code where it will be easier to format and read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
filepath <- list.files(dir,pattern = '*.txt', full.names = TRUE)

r_overall <- function(file, xx){
  aa <- readLines(file)
  bb <- grep(xx, aa, value = TRUE)
  cc <- readr::parse_number(sub(xx, '', bb))
  return(cc)
}

result <- lapply(filepath, r_overall, "The probability of being a carrier is")
```

Comment: It is working for "The probability of being a carrier is" . But if I change into "result <- lapply(filepath, r_overall, "an BRCA1 carrier"), it retain 1 for all of results. I hope the xx should be assigned as "an BRCA1 carrier"

Comment: It is by default assigned. You could also verify that since it works for "The probability of being a carrier is" . If you still want to assign it explicitly you can do `result <- lapply(filepath, r_overall, xx = "an BRCA1 carrier")` though that will not change the result. Maybe the structure of the data is different for "an BRCA1 carrier".

Comment: I did try. I think the cc return 1 from "BRCA1"  when use "result <- lapply(filepath, r_overall, xx="an BRCA1 carrier")", or return 2 from "BRCA2"  when use "result <- lapply(filepath, r_overall, xx = "an BRCA2 carrier")". How can I get the value after the string? thank you

Comment: You can try the updated answer. However, please try to provide some data that we can work with. It's difficult to write the code on the fly without being sure if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ronak's help. But I still have some additional questions:
I have series text files. each for them has similar 3 rows, see example below:

```
The probability of being a carrier is 0.07457166 
 an BRCA1 carrier 0.03181885 
 an BRCA2 carrier 0.04273394
```

when I submit the code:

```
result <- lapply(filepath, r_overall, "The probability of being a carrier is")
```

I can get the number from 1st row. but I also want to get the number for 2nd and 3rd rows

```
result <- lapply(filepath, r_overall, "an BRCA1 carrier")
result <- lapply(filepath, r_overall, "an BRCA2 carrier")
```

it return 1 and 2. I guess the code return the 1 or 2 from string BRCA1 or BRCA2. Actually,  I want to get the number after the string of "an BRCA1 carrier" or "an BRCA2 carrier". How to modify the function for this? And a few of text file may has NA values after those string. such as:

```
    The probability of being a carrier is NA 
 an BRCA1 carrier NA 
 an BRCA2 carrier 0.04273394
```

I also need the function can handle those missing values
thank you. TGG